# How are you supposed to calculate overhead expenses?

Tags: labor-economics

I'm doing a college assignment (creating a software product) in Computer Science and have been given a template for the part of the report about economics. At one moment it states the following:

`To calculate overhead expenses we must multiply our overall salary by the coefficient of overhead expenses.`

And later in the text it assumes that this coefficient is 1.2 without any context or explanation. This makes absolutely no sense to me. Am I missing something or is it wrong? If it is wrong, how am I supposed to calculate overhead expenses if every reasonable expense is already accounted for?

Answer (score 1):

Estimating overhead expenses by applying a coefficient to salaries can make sense in some circumstances.  In an organisation which is mainly office-based, overheads may consist mainly of the costs of office space, office running costs (electricity, cleaning, etc), computer equipment and support, and (depending on the local jurisdiction) payroll-related and property-related taxes. Using a fixed coefficient will always be an approximation to actual costs, but sometimes it can be a fairly good one, especially if the organisation has a fairly "flat" structure with most staff being on similar salaries and having similar office and computing needs.

In a manufacturing organisation with much capital equipment this approach would be inappropriate.